# C++ program crash ( Time limit exceeded )

Tags: c++, list

Here's the full code. If in the main while inserting elements we run the loop for less than 30 times , it runs . Else it doesn't. Program crashes and give error " Time limit exceeded in online compilers ". I wanted to see the output of all 100 random elements inserted into the list of array. But the program crashes for unknown reason to me.

Here's the main

```
int main()
{
    node* a[100],*b,*temp,*temp2;
    int num;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {    
        a[i]=NULL;;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) // If this loop is less than 30 , it runs
    {
        num=(1+ (rand() %100) );

        insert_node(a,num);
    }
    display(a);
}
```

Here's the insert function

```
void insert_node(node **q,int data)
{
    node *temp,*temp2;
    int pos;
    pos=hash_function(data);
    if(q[pos]==NULL)
    {
        temp=new node;
        temp->next=NULL;
       temp->data=data;
       q[pos]=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp2=q[pos];
        while(temp2->next != NULL )
        {
            temp2=q[pos];
            temp2=temp2->next;
        }
        temp=new node;
        temp->next=NULL;
        temp->data=data;
        temp2->next=temp;
    }
}
```

And here's the noobie hash function .

```
int hash_function(int data)
{
    return 1+(rand() %100);
}
```

Here's the display one

```
void display(node **q)
{
    node * temp;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
            temp=q[i];
            if(temp !=NULL)
        {

            cout<<"\n Position : "<<i<<" , Elements : ";
            while(temp->next != NULL)
            {
                cout<<" "<<temp->data;
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            cout<<" "<<temp->data;
        }
    }


}
```

PS: Please don't judge on my attempt towards hashing. Really a noob programmer. Thanks in advace .

Comment: "It works" or "it doesn't" are not useful statements. Please add the following to the post: What you are *expecting* to happen, and what *actually* happened

Comment: @BenWainwright , Edited. Will mind from next time.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I tried some print statements in between to check where it breaks , it prints a few and then crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
    temp2=q[pos];
    while(temp2->next != NULL )
    {
        temp2=q[pos];
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
```

Every time through the loop you set `temp2` back to `q[pos]` before going to the next. So you never get past the second element of the linked list, and it never finds the `NULL` pointer.

Get rid of the `temp=q[pos];` line in the loop, it should just be done once before the loop.

Another problem is that array indexes are zero-based, so you shouldn't add `1` when calculating the hash code.

```
int hash_function(int data)
{
    return (rand() %100);
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/zvVDg3)

Comment: Another issue: a[100] =>index 0-99; return 1+(rand() %100) =>value: 1-100 ... q[100] would be an overflow.

Comment: @Florianp.i. yeah , fixed that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Barmar ,  did what you said and totally understand the logical error. But it still happens idk why. I've put print statements all throughout , it seems it crashes only when an element already exist and we're inserting in list with some elements.

**EDIT:**Its Giving "Runtime Error" in online compilers .

Though thanks for eye pointing the logical error !!

Comment: The problem only happens when a bucket has more than 2 elements in the linked list and you try to add to it. The loop never gets past the 2nd element when looking for the end of the list. So when you have a small number of items, you don't usually get long lists, and the program works.

Comment: @Barmar , What if we want to have items ? I do understand its stupid as hash functions are meant to spread data evenly. But out curiosity , what if I want to as I don't know why it's not getting past the 2nd ?
Thanks again tho.

Comment: Because you keep setting `temp2` back to the beginning of the list. It's like if you're on a line and every time you take a step forward, you go back to the end of the line. You'll never get anywhere.

Comment: But if the list has only 1 element, the test `while (temp2->next != NULL)` fails the first time, and the loop ends.